# Language features needed for Marigold

Tags: michelson, liquidity

In the [Marigold presentation](https://medium.com/tezos/marigold-layer-2-scaling-for-tezos-7445b5a3b7be) it is stated that

> But first, project resources are dedicated to a new smart contract
>   language for Tezos. What currently exists was sufficient for the
>   Marigold prototype. However, the contracts needed for the full feature
>   set described above require more because of their additional
>   complexity.

Is there an other document or site I should read or follow to learn more about these features that would not be present in Michelson or Liquidity?

Comment: Whatever they will need that is not in Michelson (and Liquidity that has an equivalent expressivity), they will need a protocol amendment to get it. Maybe they are just looking for a better syntax, like the ReasonML syntax now available on Liquidity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires specific details about a 3rd parties intentions/opinions and doesn't relate specifically to Tezos

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to a commercial argument: it's unclear whether the authors of the original paper know themselves the reply to this question.

Comment: I edited to improve admissibility of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to follow this project: https://medium.com/tezos/introducing-ligo-a-new-smart-contract-language-for-tezos-233fa17f21c7

Not many answers for now, syntax apart, it looks like Liquidity or Fi.